# Java Stax import

Tags: java, stax

I have stateless session bean with function:

```
public ProductAttributeUnit createProductAttributeUnit(ProductAttributeUnit productAttributeUnit) 
{ 
    em.persist(productAttributeUnit); 
    return productAttributeUnit; 
}
```

Than I have another class to import from xml file

```
 @Inject private ProductAttributeService productAttributeService;
ProductAttributeUnit productAttributeUnit;
private ProductAttributeUnitTranslation productAttributeUnitTranslation;
private String tagContent;
private String node;

public void importUnits (InputStream xmlFile) throws XMLStreamException{
    XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    XMLStreamReader reader = factory.createXMLStreamReader(xmlFile);

     while(reader.hasNext()){
         int event = reader.next();

         switch(event){

             case XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT:
                 if ("Units".equals(reader.getLocalName())){
                    node = "Unit";}

                 if ("Unit".equals(reader.getLocalName())){
                    productAttributeUnit = new ProductAttributeUnit();
                 }

             break;

             case XMLStreamConstants.CHARACTERS:
                    tagContent = reader.getText().trim();
             break;

             case XMLStreamConstants.END_ELEMENT:

                 switch(reader.getLocalName()){
                     case "Code":
                         productAttributeUnit.setCode(tagContent);
                     break;                        

                     case "Unit":
                         productAttributeService.createProductAttributeUnit(productAttributeUnit);

         }
     }
}}
```

I recieve java.lang.NullPointerException. If I pass productAttributeUnit to List and than persist elements from this List everythnig works fine.

Why I can not persist it directly using JPA ?